# Using the Monero wallet RPC it takes 10 minutes to create a subaddress. What's the problem?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

Using the Monero wallet RPC command `create_address` it takes 10 minutes to create a sub address. What's the problem?

Comment: It should be instant. What OS, version etc are you running?

Comment: ubuntu os system  
monero-cli version: 0.16.0.1

Comment: `create_address` is a monero-wallet-*rpc* method, not monero-wallet-*cli*. If you are using monero-wallet-*cli*, you'd use the command `address new`.

Comment: I'm using the "create Address" command from the Monero-Wallet - RPC call

Comment: So what json are you sending? What response are you getting? What are you using to send the payload?

Comment: i send json data on 2020-08-03 13:20:54.028
"{"method":"create_address","id":"0","jsonrpc":"2.0","params":{"account_index":0}}"

Comment: XMR node response data on 2020-08-03 13:25:35.902

{
 "id": "0",
 "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 "result": {
  "address": "8BCeg7bXAVUdqViNA3KaQ2hgZzay4p1psM1hpsx9BZ16jAq6LojHEZmHRpdbd1UuUniGFZEhqRpzpL2hqrNgpVseGZQpK8E",
  "address_index": 1420,
  "address_indices": [1420],
  "addresses": ["8BCeg7bXAVUdqViNA3KaQ2hgZzay4p1psM1hpsx9BZ16jAq6LojHEZmHRpdbd1UuUniGFZEhqRpzpL2hqrNgpVseGZQpK8E"]
 }
}

Comment: Interesting. Does it take the same time under a different account_index or using a different wallet?

Comment: account_index is 0,using a different wallet is same

Comment: Is there a server configuration recommendation

Comment: I'm asking if using a different account_index (eg 1) is faster. You have a lot (1420) of addresses in account index 0, so I want to know if you have the same problem with a wallet/account without such a high number of addresses.

Comment: same situation (account_index 0 have 1145 subAddress  
account_index 1 have 2 subAddress )

Comment: I am interested in a test without such a high amount of existing addresses in the wallet. Do you experience the same slow speed with a fresh wallet?

Comment: I set up an environment on  the new machine, created a new wallet, called the "create_address" command of the RPC node and had to wait 5 minutes for the data to be returned, while the other interfaces had normal response times

Comment: The command "create address" was called with a high CPU utilization rate of 30%, while the other interface calls had a CPU utilization rate of 0

Comment: The command "create_account","create_account" was called with a high CPU utilization rate of 30%